# Lighttpd vhost setting does work for subdirectories

Tags: installation, syntax-error, lighttpd

I have the following mapping setup to take care subdirectories, but with this change lighttpd failed to start, is there anything wrong? also where can I find the system logs for lighttpd

[root@localhost log]# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start verbose
Starting lighttpd (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:443" {
  ssl.engine                  = "enable"
  ssl.pemfile                 = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/api.testdomain.com.pem"
  ssl.ca-file                 = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem.cer"

  $HTTP["host"] =~ "^api\.testdomain\.com" {
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/[^/]*\.json$" {
      server.name               = "api.testdomain.com"
      server.errorlog           = "/var/log/lighttpd/testdomain.com/server_error_443.log"
      accesslog.filename        = "/var/log/lighttpd/testdomain.com/server_access_443.log"
      proxy.server              = ( "" => ( ("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9001) ) )
    }
    else $HTTP["url"] = "^/v2/*\.json$" {
      server.name               = "api.testdomain.com"
      server.errorlog           = "/var/log/lighttpd/testdomain.com/server_error_443.log"
      accesslog.filename        = "/var/log/lighttpd/testdomain.com/server_access_443.log"
      proxy.server              = ( "" => ( ("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9004) ) )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a classic error :) You put `=` instead of `==`

```
else $HTTP["url"] == "^/v2/*\.json$" {
```

I tried it and I got the exact line/column error instead of just your "*Job failed*":

```
2012-03-24 10:26:31: (configfile.c.564) source: /etc/lighttpd/sites/test.fr line: 13 pos: 20 only =~ and == are allowed in the condition
```